# Elements acting weird in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, responsive-design

So I was building a website using HTML and CSS along with some JS. My main browser has always been Firefox and the website looks perfect on it as well. However, after opening it in Chrome, I noticed a lot has changed.

1. The fonts appear different: I tried CSS resetting and other known techniques, but I do not know why the fonts appear to be changed. What would you guys suggest in solving this issue?
2. An entire element does not even appear on Chrome and I am totally confused as to why or how that can happen.

Code:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="masked-copy texture-orange big-type">
               <p><span class="firstline">Coffee </span><span class="secondline">'N'</span> <span class="thirdline">Code!</span></p>
               <!--
                  
               -->
               <div class="explanation">
                  <h1>
                     <div class="goo" contenteditable="true">Elected as a <i>Senior Project Lead</i> <br>at the Biggest Club<br> involved in Technology and Coding: <span id = 'newline'>Coffee</span> 'N' Code.</div>
                  </h1>
                  <!-- Filter: https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/ -->
                  <svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
                     <defs>
                        <filter id="goo">
                           <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
                           <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
                           <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
                        </filter>
                     </defs>
                  </svg>
               </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .texture-orange {
    color: #e5895f;
    background-image: url('https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-xr/a/images/overview/copy_texture_4_large.jpg');
  }

.big-type { 
  /* Copied almost wholesale from the Apple site CSS; changed the font-stack */
  font-size: 60px;
  height: 60vh;
  line-height: 1.0625; /* The height Apple used to tighten up the spacing a bit. */
  font-weight: 600; /* Nice, chunky, bold! */
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
}

.masked-copy { 
  /* This is it! Magic: */
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent !important;
  
}

.project3 .goo{
  position: relative;
  top: -160px;
  left: -30px;
}
.project3 .explanation .goo #newline::before{
  content: '\a';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

*As seen on Firefox*
[image]

*As seen on Chrome*
[image]

Comment: can u share the live code?

Comment: How so? Sorry I am a beginner as mentioned,

Comment: Put your code in jsFiddle and share it :)

Comment: It looks like the font is the same, but the container as a whole is a different size as well as a css issue with your list pushing the li text onto the next line, can you inspect the elements that are different and show us what css is different please? I suspect the base em/rem is different and this is affecting the container size and then every em/rem element below that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to nest the `<h1>` tag into the `<div>` tag:

```html
 <div class="masked-copy texture-orange big-type">
               <p><span class="firstline">Coffee </span><span class="secondline">'N'</span> <span class="thirdline">Code!</span></p>
               <!--
                  
               -->
               <div class="explanation">
                  <div>
                     <h1 class="goo" contenteditable="true">Elected as a <i>Senior Project Lead</i> <br>at the Biggest Club<br> involved in Technology and Coding: <span id = 'newline'>Coffee</span> 'N' Code.</h1>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Filter: https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/ -->
                  <svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
                     <defs>
                        <filter id="goo">
                           <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
                           <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
                           <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
                        </filter>
                     </defs>
                  </svg>
               </div>
            </div>
```

Also, your code doesn't match the picture

Comment: Don't forget to click the tick to show that this was the accepted answer

Comment: Even on Google Chrome? It showed up? Why am I not able to see it then?